# Registry import from some other system's exported .reg file?

Tags: windows, registry

[image: Import .reg file]
I am trying to import .reg file which is exported from another system who is having same configuration. Is it possible? If it is possible what kind of problem i may face? Thanks in advance

Comment: That depends a whole lot on what you want to import.. It could be a single key in which case it will almost certainly work without any problem, or it could be a lot of keys containing hardcoded paths to locations that don't exist on the new system in which case it would break some functionality

Comment: @Syberdoor please make it as an answer so that i can close this question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is very hard to answer this question in general.

If you only import a single key that contains no paths that are unique to the system where you exported, it will almost certainly work without problems.
Especially all keys that are basically settings will work most of the time.

If they keys contain paths that don't exist on the other systems, or information about registered dlls/ocx files that are not present it will most certainly not work.

Keep in mind that those .reg files are all just text files, so a good idea would probably be to export it, open it with a text editor and look at what subkeys are contained within if you are unsure.

Also make a backup on the new system before the import, so you can revert all changes later.